# How to dump DozeParameters of systemUI by adb command?

Tags: android, adb, dumpsys

The dump function is implemented here:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/DozeParameters.java;l=449

Is it possible to call it by any adb shell dumpsys command?

Answer (score 1):

Those particular parameters are only available as part of a full bug report dump file.

Additionally if you use the `blame` button on your link page you'll see the function was added in 2021 / 2022, so only a recent version of Android may have that output.

On my Pixel 6a with Android 13 connected via USB cable,

I ran `adb bugreport bugreport.zip` which took a few minutes to run.

Unzipped the bugreport file and searching in the main text file I was able to find:

```
DozeParameters:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
getAlwaysOn(): false
getDisplayStateSupported(): true
getPulseDuration(): 6730
getPulseInDuration(): 130
getPulseInVisibleDuration(): 6000
getPulseOutDuration(): 600
getPulseOnSigMotion(): false
getVibrateOnSigMotion(): false
getVibrateOnPickup(): false
getProxCheckBeforePulse(): true
getPickupVibrationThreshold(): 2000
getSelectivelyRegisterSensorsUsingProx(): false
isQuickPickupEnabled(): true
```

Comment: Although your answer makes a lot of sense, I can't accept your answer right now. Because 1) this way is too slow to get the result as quickly as adb shell dumpsys | grep xxx (although I didn't bring this up when I asked the question) and 2) my Android 11 doesn't seem to output that result. Anyway, thank you very much!